# php arrange repeating items in an object

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, object, relationship

this object:

```
"permission_category": [{
        "id": 2,
        "name": "user",
        "permissions": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "userCreate"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "user",
        "permissions": {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "userUpdate"
        }
    }
]
```

can i convert it to this?

```
"permission_category": [{
        "id": 2,
        "name": "user",
        "permissions": [
            {
              "id": 2,
              "name": "userCreate"
            },
            {
              "id": 3,
              "name": "userUpdate"
            },
        ]
    }
]
```

Do I have such a chance? Because if I return this with foreach it will print the same category name more than once. Is it possible to show both userCreate and userUpdate permissions belonging to the user category under one category? The object looks like this to me. I have created a relationship between 4 tables in Laravel. I will share their code with you too. Please tell me if what I need to do is change the code between relationships. Please tell me if what I need to do is to edit the array in the output with php array functions. I don't know anything about this, I need some help. Sorry for prolonging the topic. I'm sure there's a right and easy way to do this. Since I don't know, I had to ask. I would like to express my thanks and regards to those who have helped in advance.

Laravel Relationship:

UsersController.php

```
public function add() {
        $data = array();
        $user = AdminUsers::where('id', $this->uid())->first();
        if($user->hasAdministrator()->first())
            $data['permission_category'] = PermissionCategory::with('permissions')->get();
        else
            $data['permission_category'] = PermissionsResource::collection($user->permissions()->with('category')->get());
        return $data;
        die();
        return view('admin.users.add', $data);
    }
```

PermissionsResource.php

```
return [
            "id" => $this->category[0]->id,
            "name" => $this->category[0]->name,
            "permissions" => [
                "id" => $this->id,
                "name" => $this->name
            ],
        ];
```

AdminUsers.php (Model)

```
    public function permissions() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Permissions::class, 'admin_perms');
    }
```

Permissions.php (Model)

```
    public function category() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(PermissionCategory::class, 'permissions', 'id');
    }
```

admin_users table:

```
-id
-username
```

permission_category table:

```
-id
-name
```

permissions table:

```
-id
-permission_category_id
-name
```

admin_perms table:

```
-id
-admin_users_id foreign key
-permissions_id foreign key
```

Comment: Please add your table structure to the question. It seems that one category has many permissions, and it's currently setup with `belongsToMany`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do

```
$adminPermsWithCategory = AdminPerms::with('permission.category')
->where('admin_users_id', $user->id);->get();

return new AdminPermsResource($adminPermsWithCategory);
```

and in AdminPermsResource:

```
$data = [];
foreach ($this->resource as $item) {
    if(!array_key_exists($item->permission->category->name, $data)){
        $data[$item->permission->category->name] = [
            "category_id" => $cat->id,
            "category_name" => $cat->name,
        ];
    }
    $data[$item->permission->category->name]['permissions'][$item->permission->id] = new PermissionsResource($item->permission);
}

return $data;
```

and in PermissionsResource:

```
return [
    "permission_id" => $this->id,
    "permission_name" => $this->name,
];
```

maybe this help. I am writing without trying, sorry for the answer before.

Comment: hello @Alper , first of all thank you for your reply. But it lists all the permissions in the category. It doesn't just list the permissions the user has.

I got output like this:

{
 "data": [{
  "category_id": 2,
  "category_name": "user",
  "permissions": [{
    "permission_id": 2,
    "permission_name": "userCreate"
   },
   {
    "permission_id": 3,
    "permission_name": "userUpdate"
   },
   {
    "permission_id": 4,
    "permission_name": "userDelete"
   },
   {
    "permission_id": 5,
    "permission_name": "userShow"
   }
  ]
 }]
}

Comment: Sorry for that. I edited the reply for the situation. But i didn't try the code and not sure if the best solution. I think it could help you for the situation. @HuseyinTelli